# emacs -- keybind questions

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I have successfully used <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Up</kbd> ' <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+down</kbd> '

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+left</kbd>' <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Right</kbd> to different commands. But when I

tried to use <kbd>Ctrl+s</kbd> to the command save-buffer and <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+s</kbd>, which

is equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd>, to another command, it has some problem.

save-buffer works fine, but when I type <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+s</kbd>, it excute

the command save-buffer. I used <kbd>Ctrl+q</kbd> to find the control sequences of

<kbd>Ctrl+s</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+S</kbd>, I get the same result, which is <kbd>^S</kbd>.

I expect that I will get <kbd>^s</kbd> for <kbd>Ctrl+s</kbd>, but it doesn't.

Anyone knows the reason?

Another queston is: I use <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> for the command killing-ring-save. In this

case, all commands (which are of large number) begin with <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> don't work now.

Is there a way to replace the prefix <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> by another customized prefix?

---

I may pose my question in the wrong direction. I use <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> as

killing-ring-save. It works fine in emacs (no mode). But if I open a .c file (C-mode), then

when I type <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd>, it waits me to type another key. I think in this case,

<kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> is regarded as a prefix. In this case, I need the following modifications:

Using a custom defined prefix, say <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd>, as <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> ; Remove the

prefix <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> ; Using <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd>  as killing-ring-save.

I add the following to my ~/.emacs :

(global-set-key (kbd "C-a") mode-specific-map)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c") 'kill-ring-save)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'isearch-forward)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-v") 'yank)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-s") 'save-buffer)

(defun my-c-initialization-hook ()

(define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "C-a") mode-specific-map)

(define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "C-c") 'kill-ring-save))

(add-hook 'c-initialization-hook 'my-c-initialization-hook)

But this doesn't work. <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> is still regarded as a prefix, so I can't use it

as kill-ring-save. Furthermore, if I type <kbd>Ctrl+a Ctrl+c</kbd>, it said it's not

defined. (I thought it will have the same result as I type <kbd>Ctrl+c Ctrl+c</kbd>)

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <kbd>C-c</kbd> binding is tricky, CUA mode solves it well, by only making it do kill-ring-save when you have a region marked.

Answer (score 1):

First, Control-S is an ASCII control character -- `^s` and `^S` are the same character.

Keys are something different from characters, however, and if you are using Emacs with a window manager then you can distinguish the keys <kbd>C-s</kbd> and <kbd>C-S-s</kbd>. The latter is Control-Shift-s.

The problem you are hitting is that if you do not explicitly bind the shifted version of a letter key, then the shifted letter key uses the binding of the unshifted key. This is a "feature".

So you need to bind both <kbd>C-s</kbd> and <kbd>C-S-s</kbd>.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s") 'save-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-s") 'another-command)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running emacs in a terminal, then the reason for the shift-ctl-c issue could be the terminal driver. In that case, give the command `stty stop undef`, then run emacs again, and see if it affects the problem. Also, see if you get same problem with shift-ctl-*other letters*

Comment: No, it doesn't work. shift-ctl-letters always have the same control sequence the one of ctl-letters. For example, shift-ctl-a and ctl-a both give me ^A, not ^a

Comment: Found in the manual : http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html#Modifier-Keys

Comment: A <Control>-modified alphabetical character is always considered case-insensitive: Emacs always treats C-A as C-a, C-B as C-b, and so forth. The reason for this is historical. (But anyone knows the historical reason?)